# How to save your high-score

Tags: java, android, preferences, shared, save

I want to save my best, only one high-score to file, and then if game is on to show it on menu screen.

Like this:

> Best: Points.

I have my points and they count until you die, but then I don't know how to save them. I heard about Share Preferences. But can someone give me example, the best way to do it. I have code checking if your points isn't better then best high-score, but don't know how to save them properly. Any advise or help is appreciated!

Comment: If you've heard of sharedpreferences, is it really easier to ask here than to google about them?   The first page has a half dozen tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very quick sample, assuming that you want to store and load your preferences from an `Activity`.

To store your values in preferences:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("best_score", numberOfPoints);
editor.commit();
```

To load the value:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
if (sharedPreferences.contains("best_score")) {
    // we have a high score saved, load it...
    int numberOfPoints = sharedPreferences.getInt("best_score", -1);
    // here you'd like to do something with the value, for example display it.
} else {
    // there is no high score value - you should probably hide the "best score" TextView
}
```

The `"best_score"` is just a key under which you tell Android to store the value - it can be anything, but it's important for the key to be the same every time you want to access/manipulate the same value - in your case "best score".

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article on different storage options: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html It also describes SharedPreferences in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should store a high score in an SQLite DB. However the SharedPrefs option is also viable.